# validating fields that depend on one another

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my Rails app I have classes that depend on one another, `ParkingSpace` and `Parking Lot`.

A `ParkingLot` has many `ParkingSpaces` and the `ParkingSpace` belongs to a `ParkingLot`.

I want to ensure that the same `ParkingSpace` can't be inserted into the `ParkingLot` again.

Typically, I would use a uniqueness validation to ensure that the ParkingSpace can't be repeated parking space have very generic names

`ParkingLot` with id:1 can have `ParkingSpaces` 1, 2 and 3 on it.

`ParkingLot` with id:2 can also have `ParkingSpaces` 1, 2 and 3 on it.

But the above parking lots should not be able to have two parking spaces with the same name.

How can I validate this in Rails?
How can I validate this at the database level?

I'm considering joining the two fields together in a unique way and then calling unique on that. Is this a valid approach? (Not exactly sure how to do this at the database level, but all my validations need to be present there.)

(using Postgres)

Comment: If your rails app is the only app that uses the db, you do not need to validate on the db level.

Comment: Are there two Spaces with the same name or is there one and only one Space with name "1" that is used in a bunch of different lots?

Comment: @Charles - My rails app will be using a shared database. Any tips?

Comment: @JohnNaegle - yes, there will be multiple parking spaces with the same "1" for a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your parking space and an identifier (like a name), you would do something in the ParkingSpace class like:

```
class ParkingSpace < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :parking_lot

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :parking_lot_id

end
```

Comment: do you know how i would do this at the db level?

Answer (score 0):

well since parking # belongs to to parking lot. you would add a uniquness validation to the parking lot model that validates unqiuness of :parkingspace_id

you're creating a parking spot object that has a unique id so parking space #1 would be  id = 1. if you validate the uniquness of the id then you will ensure that another parking lot can add it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this gem: "Sexy PG constraints is closer to the answer."\

https://github.com/maxim/sexy_pg_constraints

Feel free to add to it, or explain anything from it.

From the documentation

> Multi-column constraints
>
> Say you have the same table “books” only now you want to tell your
>   Postgres to make sure that you should never have the same title +
>   author_id combination. It means that you want to apply uniqueness to
>   two columns, not just one. There is a special syntax for working with
>   multicolumn constraints.

```
class AddConstraintsToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    constrain :books do |t|
      t[:title, :author_id].all :unique => true # Notice how multiple columns are listed in brackets.
    end
  end

  def self.down
    deconstrain :books do |t|
      t[:title, :author_id].all :unique
    end
  end
end
```

> It’s important to note that you shouldn’t mix multicolumn constraints
>   with regular ones in one line. This may cause unexpected behavior.